Will pop scope is deprecated
I have used WillPopScope
WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () => willPopScopeWid(),
            child:Container(
//SomeCode
)),

willPopScopeWid() {
    setState(() {
      onTapOfVideo = false;
    });
    return Navigator.pop(context);
  }

Is there any other way to get rid of deprecated Widget?

Use PopScope as WillPopScope is deprecated.

It's not working

Change willPopScopeWid method return type of bool as your requirement and pass to PopScope's canPop: willPopScopeWid()

Still it's not working

see Android predictive back

This question is similar to: WillPopScope is deprecated after flutter 3.12. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have added like this PopScope( canPop: true, onPopInvoked: (didPop) { setState(() { onTapOfVideo = false; }); Navigator.pop(context); }, child: // Your child widget) but still not working

Its working, i have used Navigator.pop(context),after removed it, it worked

Yes, WillPopScope widget is deprecated and is replaced by just PopScope here's how you can use PopScope:
  PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        // when pressing back button this is a callback for
      },
      child: YourWidget()
     )


It's not working

I have added like this PopScope( canPop: true, onPopInvoked: (didPop) { setState(() { onTapOfVideo = false; }); Navigator.pop(context); }, child: // Your child widget) but still not working

Its working, i have used Navigator.pop(context),after removed it, it worked

@MoonPrincess good for you.
